# Parse server login with useMasterKey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-server

I fail to login with [parse-server](/questions/tagged/parse-server) using masterkey, no error is thrown but nothing happens either. I have waited 10 minutes for a response, but the server refuses to log anything. Here is my code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage)
    Parse.initialize("myapp1", "thisismymasterkey")
    Parse.serverURL = "http://server_ip:3333/myapp1";
    Parse.masterKey = "thisismymasterkey";
}

userLogin = () => {
    let userName = 'admin'
    let userPass = '123'
    this.loading = true
    Parse.User.logIn(userName , userPass , {useMasterKey : true}, {
        success: (user) => {
            // Do stuff after successful login, like a redirect.
            console.log('User logged in successful with username: ' +
                         user.get("username") + ' and email: ' +
                         user.get("email"))

//...
```

How can I properly use `useMasterKey : true` in my code ?

Comment: I believe this is some client code, and you should NEVER use the masterKey on the client, we've stressed it out enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some client code, and you should **NEVER** use the masterKey on the client, we've stressed it out enough.

if you still want to do this silly thing, you should probably use the promise API:

```
Parse.User.logIn(userName , userPass, /* {useMasterKey: true } */)
.then(user => {

}).catch(error => {

});
```

or if you really want to stick to the backbone style API which will be removed soon:

```
Parse.User.logIn(userName , userPass, {
    /* useMasterKey: true, */
    success: (user) => {

    },
    error: (error) => {}
});
```